# Sed replace with carriage returns

Tags: unix, sed

Sed replaces with carriage returns.

My file:

```
<ABC>123</ABC><ABC>456</ABC>
```

I want to output like this:

```
<ABC>123</ABC>
<ABC>456</ABC>
```

I am using:

```
sed "s/<ABC>///n/g"
```

But there isn't any changes.

Comment: sorry,  typing mistake!  sed "s/ <ABC>//n <ABC>/g"

Comment: i want to add a carriage return after <ABC>

Comment: Ah, SO ate your slashes. I fixed it. Though that's still too many slashes and still causes an error with sed here. Why do you have so many slashes in the sed script? The format is `s/pattern/replacement/g`. Did you mean `\\n` instead of `//n`?

Comment: yes, \\n is correct, i try it before

Comment: And `sed "s/<ABC>/\\n/g"` (or even just `sed "s/<ABC>/\n/g"`) didn't work?

Comment: it did not work, I'm using AIX 9.5

Comment: Try `\r` instead of `\n` maybe? What version of sed do you have?

Answer (score 2):

Try as below

```
sed -e 's/></>\n</g' file.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: Thank you five years later.